# Pytorch transformer forward function masks implementation for decoder forward function

Tags: pytorch, forward, transformer-model, encoder-decoder

I am trying to use and learn PyTorch Transformer with DeepMind math dataset. I have tokenized (char not word) sequence that is fed into model. Models forward function is doing once forward for encoder and multiple forwards for decoder (till all batch outputs reach  token, this is still TODO).
I am struggling with Transformer masks and decoder forward as it throws the error:

```
    k = k.contiguous().view(-1, bsz * num_heads, head_dim).transpose(0, 1)
    RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 24, 64]' is invalid for input of size 819200.
```

Source is N = 32, S = 50, E = 512. Target is N = 32, S = 3, E = 512.
It is possible that I have wrong implementation of masks or that source and target lengths are different, not realy sure.

```
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):   
# function to positionally encode src and target sequencies 
def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=5000):
    super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
    pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
    position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
    div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
    pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
    pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
    pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
    self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

def forward(self, x):
    x = x + self.pe[:x.size(0), :]
    return self.dropout(x)

class MyTransformerModel(nn.Module):
# should implement init and forward function
# define separate functions for masks
# define forward function with
# implement:
#  embedding layer
#  positional encoding
#  encoder layer
#  decoder layer
#  final classification layer
# encoder -> forward once
# decoder -> forward multiple times (for one encoder forward)
# decoder output => concatenate to input e.g. decoder_input = torch.cat([decoder_input], [decoder_output])
# early stopping => all in batch reach <eos> token
def __init__(self, vocab_length = 30, sequence_length = 512, num_encoder_layers = 3, num_decoder_layers = 2, num_hidden_dimension = 256, feed_forward_dimensions = 1024, attention_heads = 8, dropout = 0.1, pad_idx = 3, device = "CPU", batch_size = 32):
    super(MyTransformerModel, self).__init__()
    self.src_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_length, sequence_length)
    self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(sequence_length, dropout)
    self.src_mask = None # attention mask
    self.memory_mask = None # attention mask
    self.pad_idx = pad_idx        
    self.device = device        
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
        sequence_length,
        attention_heads,
        num_encoder_layers,
        num_decoder_layers,
        feed_forward_dimensions,
        dropout,
    )
    
def src_att_mask(self, src_len):
    mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(src_len, src_len)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
    mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
    return mask


def no_peak_att_mask(self, batch_size, src_len, time_step):
    mask = np.zeros((batch_size, src_len), dtype=bool)
    mask[:, time_step: ] = 1 # np.NINF
    mask = torch.from_numpy(mask)
    return mask

def make_src_key_padding_mask(self, src):
    # mask "<pad>"
    src_mask = src.transpose(0, 1) == self.pad_idx
    return src_mask.to(self.device)

def make_trg_key_padding_mask(self, trg):
    tgt_mask = trg.transpose(0, 1) == self.pad_idx
    return tgt_mask.to(self.device)


def forward(self, src, trg):
    src_seq_length, N = src.shape
    trg_seq_length, N = trg.shape
    embed_src = self.src_embedding(src)
    position_embed_src =  self.pos_encoder(embed_src)
    embed_trg = self.src_embedding(trg)
    position_embed_trg = self.pos_encoder(embed_trg)        
    src_padding_mask = self.make_src_key_padding_mask(src)
    trg_padding_mask = self.make_trg_key_padding_mask(trg)
    trg_mask = self.transformer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(trg_seq_length).to(self.device)
    time_step = 1
    att_mask = self.no_peak_att_mask(self.batch_size, src_seq_length, time_step).to(self.device)
    encoder_output = self.transformer.encoder.forward(position_embed_src, src_key_padding_mask = src_padding_mask)
    # TODO : implement loop for transformer decoder forward fn, implement early stopping
    # where to feed decoder_output?
    decoder_output = self.transformer.decoder.forward(position_embed_trg, encoder_output, trg_mask, att_mask, trg_padding_mask, src_padding_mask)
    return decoder_output
```

Can anyone pin point where I have made a mistake?

Comment: Can you say more about what `S` signifies and why it is 50 in the source and 3 in the target? It's suspicious to me that 50 is not evenly divisible by 3, which may also be why it is complaining that `shape '[-1, 24, 64]' is invalid for input of size 819200` as 819200 is not evenly divisible by (24*64).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I have messed dimensions order (as Transformer does not have batch first option). Corrected code is below:

```
class MyTransformerModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, d_model = 512, vocab_length = 30, sequence_length = 512, num_encoder_layers = 3, num_decoder_layers = 2, num_hidden_dimension = 256, feed_forward_dimensions = 1024, attention_heads = 8, dropout = 0.1, pad_idx = 3, device = "CPU", batch_size = 32):
    #, ninp, device, nhead=8, nhid=2048, nlayers=2, dropout=0.1, src_pad_idx = 1, max_len=5000, forward_expansion= 4):
    super(MyTransformerModel, self).__init__()
    self.src_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_length, d_model)
    self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(d_model, dropout)
    self.vocab_length = vocab_length
    self.d_model = d_model
    self.src_mask = None # attention mask
    self.memory_mask = None # attention mask
    self.pad_idx = pad_idx        
    self.device = device        
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
        d_model,
        attention_heads,
        num_encoder_layers,
        num_decoder_layers,
        feed_forward_dimensions,
        dropout,
    )

    self.fc = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_length)
    # self.init_weights() <= used in tutorial

def src_att_mask(self, src_len):
    mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(src_len, src_len)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
    mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
    return mask


def no_peak_att_mask(self, batch_size, src_len, time_step):
    mask = np.zeros((batch_size, src_len), dtype=bool)
    mask[:, time_step: ] = 1 # np.NINF
    mask = torch.from_numpy(mask)
    # mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
    return mask

def make_src_key_padding_mask(self, src):
    # mask "<pad>"
    src_mask = src.transpose(0, 1) == self.pad_idx
    # src_mask = src == self.pad_idx
    # (N, src_len)
    return src_mask.to(self.device)

def make_trg_key_padding_mask(self, trg):
    # same as above -> expected tgt_key_padding_mask: (N, T)
    tgt_mask = trg.transpose(0, 1) == self.pad_idx
    # tgt_mask = trg == self.pad_idx
    # (N, src_len)
    return tgt_mask.to(self.device)


def init_weights(self):
    initrange = 0.1
    nn.init.uniform_(self.encoder.weight, -initrange, initrange)
    nn.init.zeros_(self.decoder.weight)
    nn.init.uniform_(self.decoder.weight, -initrange, initrange)

def forward(self, src, trg):
    N, src_seq_length = src.shape
    N, trg_seq_length = trg.shape        
    #  S - source sequence length
    #  T - target sequence length
    #  N - batch size
    #  E - feature number
    #  src: (S, N, E) (sourceLen, batch, features)
    #  tgt: (T, N, E)
    #  src_mask: (S, S)
    #  tgt_mask: (T, T)
    #  memory_mask: (T, S)
    #  src_key_padding_mask: (N, S)
    #  tgt_key_padding_mask: (N, T)
    #  memory_key_padding_mask: (N, S)
    src = rearrange(src, 'n s -> s n')
    trg = rearrange(trg, 'n t -> t n')
    print("src shape {}".format(src.shape))
    print(src)
    print("trg shape {}".format(trg.shape))
    print(trg)

    embed_src = self.src_embedding(src)
    print("embed_src shape {}".format(embed_src.shape))
    print(embed_src)
    position_embed_src =  self.pos_encoder(embed_src)
    print("position_embed_src shape {}".format(position_embed_src.shape))
    print(position_embed_src)
    embed_trg = self.src_embedding(trg)
    print("embed_trg shape {}".format(embed_trg.shape))
    print(embed_trg)
    position_embed_trg = self.pos_encoder(embed_trg)
    # position_embed_trg = position_embed_trg.transpose(0, 1)
    print("position_embed_trg shape {}".format(position_embed_trg.shape))
    print(position_embed_trg)
    src_padding_mask = self.make_src_key_padding_mask(src)
    print("KEY - src_padding_mask shape {}".format(src_padding_mask.shape))
    print("should be of shape: src_key_padding_mask: (N, S)")
    print(src_padding_mask)
    trg_padding_mask = self.make_trg_key_padding_mask(trg)
    print("KEY - trg_padding_mask shape {}".format(trg_padding_mask.shape))
    print("should be of shape: trg_key_padding_mask: (N, T)")
    print(trg_padding_mask)
    trg_mask = self.transformer.generate_square_subsequent_mask(trg_seq_length).to(self.device)
    print("trg_mask shape {}".format(trg_mask.shape))
    print("trg_mask should be of shape tgt_mask: (T, T)")
    print(trg_mask)
    # att_mask = self.src_att_mask(trg_seq_length).to(self.device)
    time_step = 1
    # error => memory_mask: expected shape! (T, S) !!! this is not a key_padding_mask!
    # att_mask = self.no_peak_att_mask(self.batch_size, src_seq_length, time_step).to(self.device)
    # print("att_mask shape {}".format(att_mask.shape))
    # print("att_mask should be of shape  memory_mask: (T, S)")
    # print(att_mask)
    att_mask = None
    # get encoder output
    # forward(self, src: Tensor, mask: Optional[Tensor] = None, src_key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None)
    # forward encoder just once for a batch
    # attention forward of encoder expects => src, src_mask, src_key_padding_mask +++ possible positional encoding error !!!
    encoder_output = self.transformer.encoder.forward(position_embed_src, src_key_padding_mask = src_padding_mask)
    print("encoder_output")  
    print("encoder_output shape {}".format(encoder_output.shape))
    print(encoder_output)  
    # forward decoder till all in batch did not reach <eos>?
    # def forward(self, tgt: Tensor, memory: Tensor, tgt_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
    # memory_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None, tgt_key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
    # memory_key_padding_mask: Optional[Tensor] = None)
    # first forward
    decoder_output = self.transformer.decoder.forward(position_embed_trg, encoder_output, trg_mask, att_mask, trg_padding_mask, src_padding_mask)
    # TODO: target in => target out shifted by one, loop till all in batch meet stopping criteria || max len is reached
    # 
    print("decoder_output")  
    print("decoder_output shape {}".format(decoder_output.shape))
    print(decoder_output)
    
    output = rearrange(decoder_output, 't n e -> n t e')
    output =  self.fc(output)
    print("output")  
    print("output shape {}".format(output.shape))
    print(output)

    predicted = F.log_softmax(output, dim=-1)
    print("predicted")  
    print("predicted shape {}".format(predicted.shape))
    print(predicted)
    # top k
    top_value, top_index = torch.topk(predicted, k=1)
    top_index = torch.squeeze(top_index)
    print("top_index")  
    print("top_index shape {}".format(top_index.shape))
    print(top_index)
    print("top_value")  
    print("top_value shape {}".format(top_value.shape))
    print(top_value)
    return top_index
```

Comment: Hi Amir. You can find the code on github [link](https://github.com/tulacik/PyTorchTransformerProject)
The code is not optimal as some evaluation is done on GPU, doing it on CPU would be much quicker. Best regards, Roman